# JenkinsFile Execution for Dynamic Command via Pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

pipeline {
agent any
stages {
stage('Deploy') {
steps {
retry(3) {
sh './flakey-deploy.sh migrateOut --argFile sourcearg.txt --encassAsPolicyDependency --dest OTK.xml --folderName /OTK'
}
}
}
}
}

I would like to call this part of command "migrateOut --argFile sourcearg.txt --encassAsPolicyDependency --dest OTK.xml --folderName /OTK" from file placed in jenkins workspace.

TIA

Comment: I did not get your question. Could you clarify what you are trying? and what you have done so far. what error you are getting, etc  ?

Comment: "migrateOut --argFile sourcearg.txt --encassAsPolicyDependency --dest OTK.xml --folderName /OTK", command in double quotes here is user input which is differs for different users. Now we have hardcoded the above in the jenkinsfile of the pipeline (part of script pasted in the question).

Comment: We were planning to push the command as a text file instead of hardcoding. Is this the right approach ? or kindly suggest any other approach for this use case.

Comment: yes, it can be done 2 ways. With Jenkins Parameter - meaning when user clicks on build on the Jenkins job they can provide the command or if a file contains the command it can be read and make use of - If this is your expectation ..I will try to create an example

Comment: yes, I am expecting the same.